# Problema com conexão ao banco de dados mysql configurado mais nao sobe

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou tentando subir um sistema local porem nao esta conectando ao banco de dados.
Ja realizei as configurações.
vou deixar o erro abaixo se auguem puder me ajudar agradeço.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

aqui e a configuração no banco de dados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

codigo da linha 124

```
    // Connect to the database and set the connection ID
    $this->conn_id = ($this->pconnect == FALSE) ? $this->db_connect() : $this->db_pconnect();

    // No connection resource?  Throw an error
    if ( ! $this->conn_id)
    {
        log_message('error', 'Unable to connect to the database');

        if ($this->db_debug)
        {
            $this->display_error('db_unable_to_connect');
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Comment: o que tem na linha 124 do db_driver.php ?

Comment: esta com esse codigo
 function initialize()
 {
  
  if (is_resource($this->conn_id) OR is_object($this->conn_id))
  {
   return TRUE;
  }
  // Connect to the database and set the connection ID
  $this->conn_id = ($this->pconnect == FALSE) ? $this->db_connect() : $this->db_pconnect();
  // No connection resource?  Throw an error
  if ( ! $this->conn_id)
  {
   log_message('error', 'Unable to connect to the database');
   if ($this->db_debug)
   {
  linha --124--->    $this->display_error('db_unable_to_connect');
   }
   return FALSE;
  }

Comment: [Edit] a pergunta e coloque o código nela... fora a mensagem do browser, há outra mensagem de erro ??

Comment: ok mais veja la por favor respondendo sua outra pergunta nao apenas da esse erro conforme a foto

Comment: Qual versão do php vc usa?

Comment: dos sistema e 5.3 ja o easy php nao sei

Comment: no easyphp 5.6.19